# Android : Bitmap causing out of memory error

Tags: android, bitmap

I have been going crazy with this android error and from browsing the previous posts about this error none of the solutions that were given helped me.

I am of course talking about the all powerful killer known as the 'android Out of memory on a (NUMBER)-byte allocation.' I am trying to create a photo uploader and after the 3rd maybe 4th image my app crashes. I know to stop the crash to use a catch exception however that is not my problem. I am here to ask the community is there any solution to fixing this byte allocation error ?

Here is a snippet of my code involving the bit map .

```
        String post = editTextPost.getText().toString().trim();
        // get the photo :
        Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)postImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // compress the image to jpg format :
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 45, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String encodeImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
        // Recycle bitmap :
        image.recycle();
        image=null;

        // send data :
        sendPost p = new sendPost(this);
        p.execute(post, encodeImage);
        imageBytes=null;
```

Im not using any libraries and would like to keep it that way however if using a library is the only option I will use one. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: I don't believe that recycle removes the image right away from memory. It depend on the garbage collector. recycle doesn't force it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmaps won't completely recycle if they are attached to a View, for example to a ImageView, if you do `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`, you need to clear it before doing `imageView.setImageBitmap(null)` and clearing any other reference to any view.

Answer (score 0):

After you finish uplloading the image release the memory occupied by the "`postImage`" -

```
postImage.setImageDrawable(null);
```

This will release any memory occupied by the bitmap associated with `postImage`

Answer (score 0):

**General Answer:**

> When you upload files you need to open a stream to your server and to
>   your file at same time. read and write chunk by chunk of 1 MB for
>   example. this way you will not get an out of memory exception.